# How to Mock a method in a class that inherited Abstract class using MsTest Moq

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, moq, mstest

```
internal abstract class ClassA {
{
  internal abstract Task getInfoById(int id);
  internal async Task getDetails()
  {
    // some details
  }
}
public class ClassB: ClassA {
 internal override async Task getInfoById(int id){
    //some code processing
   await getDetails();
   }
 }
```

In the above code, How to mock getDetails() while writing test for getInfoById method for classB using MsTest and Moq

Comment: sorry, where is `doSomething` method you are trying to test? Please update your question

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to imagine where "doSomething" is in your ClassB class as it isn't there at the time of this answer. That said, you should not mock "getDetails" as it is technically part of the service under test (by virtue of it being a component of the base class). It would be appropriate to extract the functionality of "getDetails" out to a separate class with an interface of which you could mock, however.